# T-sql returns smallint as string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

When I declare a variable @Number of type SMALLINT in a Transact-SQL query, It outputs as a string, I can also compare the variable to strings. For example:

```
DECLARE @Number SMALLINT 
SET @Number = 12
IF (@Number LIKE '12')
    SET @Number = 1
SELECT @Number
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Tip: SQL Server can provide the data type of a variable explicitly. Try `declare @Number as SmallInt = 12; select @Number, sql_variant_property( @Number, 'basetype' ) AS basetype;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `==`operator doesn't exists in tsql. You need to use a single `=`.

[List of operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx)

```
DECLARE @Number SMALLINT 
SET @Number = 12
IF (@Number = 12)
    SET @Number = 1
SELECT @Number
```

Comment: Whilst you are right, the variable is outputted as a string. When I vardump the query result in PHP, I get something like:
    ["@Number"]=>
    string(1) "1"

Comment: It is a smallint tho, I believe you must be reading it wrong in PHP but I got no experience in that...

Comment: I thought that the problem was the smallint as well, but it isn't. An int variable returns a string as well... However, when I SELECT an int from my database, and vardump it, it does return a value of type int. Anyways, I've marked your answer as correct, because you were right, and I feel like the dumbest person in the world right now.

Comment: @joristt You're using PHP to tell you what data type SQL Server is outputting?

Comment: Haha no. PHP had some problems with a more advanced query, so I decided to quickly write this simple one (in my PHP file) and dump the results to check out if it worked.